# How to map JSON (custom)

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm a beginner and I need to sort from a JSON to be analyzed later.
I need to know the JSON fields and if it has arrays or subcategories.
I have to map JSON input, for example:

```
{  
   "car":"Audi",
   "model":"2010",
   "price":"30000",
   "colors":[  
      "Grey",
      "White",
      "Black"
   ],
   "otro":{  
      "a":1,
      "b":2,
      "c":[  
         {  
            "c11":"c11",
            "c12":"c12"
         },
         {  
            "c21":"c21",
            "c22":"c22"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Waiting as output mapping:

```
car
model
price
colors[]
otro.a
otro.b
otro.c[].c11
otro.c[].c12
otro.c[].c21
otro.c[].c22
```

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = "{\"car\":\"Audi\",\"model\":\"2010\",\"price\":\"30000\",\"colors\":[\"Grey\",\"White\",\"Black\"],\"otro\":{\"a\":1,\"b\":2,\"c\":[{\"c11\":\"c11\", \"c12\":\"c12\"},{\"c21\":\"c21\", \"c22\":\"c22\"}]}}";

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        // convert JSON string to Map
        map = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
        });

        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue().getClass());
            if (entry.getValue() instanceof List) {
                for (Object object : ((List)entry.getValue())) {
                    System.out.println("\t-- " + object.getClass());
                }
            }

        }

    } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a POJO and map the JSON to the POJO and do whatever you would like with it. Another option that is pretty powerful is using the JsonNode objects. They have lots of helper methods for figuring out the types of each node. Here are some quick examples https://www.stubbornjava.com/posts/practical-jackson-objectmapper-configuration#jsonnodes-and-nested-objects